# Type string | null is not assignable to type string? How do fix this in Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with an angular app that has a node express backend.  I am using an authorization service to keep my logic.  Using the same login I used in previous applications only for some reason now I am getting this error of type string | null is not assignable to type string.  What do I need to do to fix this.  I have tried declaring the string as empty in the logout method and setting the line 106 from this.userId = authInformation.userId to this.userId = authInformation.userId as string within the autoAuthUser method, however with this code before when you refresh the browser it would read the local storage and a user would remain logged in.  Now when I execute the code, it is not keeping the user logged in when refreshing the page and throws these errors when I use the original code which is as follows.

```
import { AuthData } from '../models/auth-data.model';
import { environment } from '../../../../environments/environment';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

const BACKEND = environment.authUrl;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  private token: string;
  private isAuthenticated = false;
  private tokenTimer: any;
  private userId: string;

  private authStatusListener = new Subject<boolean>();


  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router,
  ) { }

  //Get the authentication token
  getToken() {
    return this.token;
  }
  //Create a method to return the authentication status of a user after logging in
  getIsAuth() {
    return this.isAuthenticated;
  }
  //return the authentication status true or false as an observable
  getAuthStatusListener() {
    return this.authStatusListener.asObservable();
  }

getUserId() {
  return this.userId;
}

registerUser(user_email: string, user_password: string) {
  const authData: AuthData = {
    user_email: user_email,
    user_password: user_password
  }
  this.http.post(BACKEND + '/signup', authData)
  .subscribe(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['/'])
  }, error => {
    this.authStatusListener.next(false);
  })
}

loginUser(user_email: string, user_password: string) {
  const authData: AuthData = {
    user_email: user_email,
    user_password: user_password
  }
  this.http.post<{ token: string, expiresIn: number, userId: string }>(
    BACKEND + '/login',
    authData
  ).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
    const token = response.token;
    this.token = token;
    if(token) {
      const expiresInDuration = response.expiresIn;
      this.setAuthTimer(expiresInDuration);
      this.isAuthenticated = true;
      this.userId = response.userId;
      this.authStatusListener.next(true);
      const now = new Date();
      const expirationDate = new Date(now.getTime() + expiresInDuration * 1000);
      console.log(expirationDate);
      this.saveAuthData(token, expirationDate, this.userId);
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
  }, error => {
    this.authStatusListener.next(false);
  });
}
autoAuthUser() {
  const authInformation = this.getAuthData();
  if(!authInformation) {
    return;
  }
  const now = new Date();
  const expiresIn = authInformation.expirationDate.getTime() - now.getTime();
  //console.log(authInformation, expiresIn);
  if(expiresIn > 0) {
    this.token = authInformation.token;
    this.isAuthenticated = true;
    //property has to be declared as a string with the new typescript.
    this.userId = authInformation.userId;
    this.setAuthTimer(expiresIn / 1000);
    this.authStatusListener.next(true);
  }
}

logoutUser() {
  //property can no longer be set to null with the new typescript. this.token and this.userId
  this.token = null;
  this.isAuthenticated = false;
  this.authStatusListener.next(false);
  clearTimeout(this.tokenTimer);
  this.userId = null;
  this.clearAuthData();
  this.router.navigate(['/']);
}

private setAuthTimer(duration: number) {
  console.log("Setting timer: " + duration);
  this.tokenTimer = setTimeout(() => {
            this.logoutUser();
          }, duration * 1000)
  }

  private saveAuthData(token: string, expirationDate: Date, userId: string) {
  localStorage.setItem('token', token);
  localStorage.setItem('expiration', expirationDate.toISOString());
  localStorage.setItem('userId', userId);
  }

  private clearAuthData() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    localStorage.removeItem('expiration');
    localStorage.removeItem('userId');
  }

  private getAuthData() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const expirationDate = localStorage.getItem('expiration');
    const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
    if(!token || !expirationDate) {
      return;
    }
    return {
      token: token,
      expirationDate: new Date(expirationDate),
      userId: userId
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the errors I am receiving in my VSC code window. [image]

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix the errors and get the service to work correctly again?

Comment: Declare `userId` -> `private userId: string | null;`?

Comment: You really need a custom interface of `authorizationInformation` that enforces typing everywhere it is used. When used, the collection of data is used together everywhere. So enforcing the interface contract makes sense. Otherwise you are using parts and pieces without any congruence and will continue to run into odd issues like this along the way.

Comment: I am fairly new at this and am not sure I understand what you mean, It sounds like you're saying I should make an authorization model which I know how to do but I am not sure how to implement it with this application.  @RandyCasburn.

Comment: I'm not referring to a "model", but it looks and feels that way if you are not accustomed to this type of thing. What I mentioned was and [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) - you should investigate those.

Comment: Thank you.  I will do that, I appreciate it. @Randy Casburn